# Saving an array of data to cache

Tags: php, laravel

My understanding of cache might be blurry. But i am trying to save an array of record ids to cache and get them. I know the normal way of putting data in cache is

```
$expiresAt = now()->addMinutes(10);

Cache::put('key', 'value', $expiresAt);
```

and then to get is

```
Cache::get('key');
```

With each record i save to the cache, when i do `dd(Cache::get('key'));` i only get the last saved record. how can i save and get an array of data with cache ?

Comment: what you put in cache it you get back. If you get different values you need to use different keys. If you get Array you put array into cache.

Answer (score 1):

Cache value is saved under specific `key`. If you put multiple values into Cache with same key then only last value will be saved and retrived.

You can use it like below

```
$articles = [...];

foreach($articles as $article)
{
    $expiresAt = now()->addMinutes(10);

    Cache::put('key_' . $article.ID, 'value', $expiresAt);
}
```

and later use

```
Cache::get('key_' . $article.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply put to `value` an array then next time you get it from cache, it will be an array.